# IIF statement not showing the tablix values

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

I am building a report in report builder 3.0 with 3 tables.

Table 1: ABC

Table 2: DEF

Table 3: GHI

My report contains a drop down list of these 3 tables, I am using the IIF statement to hide the other 2 tables when 1 of them is selected.

For example, I choose **ABC**, the other tables **DEF and GHI** are hidden.

The statement is... **=iif(Parameters!Deliverable.Value="ABC", False, True)**

My problem, I also have another item in the drop down list that says **"All"** which should display all 3 of the tables. In order to do that I added this to every visibility expression... **=iif(Parameters!Deliverable.Value="ABC" OR Parameters!Deliverable.Value="All", False, True)**.

This ended up giving me the tablix only... not the data that was inside it. What should I do to fix it?

[The empty Tablix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS1ec.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `IIF` in this instance you just need to write an expression that evaluates to `true` or `false`.

For you 'ABC' table the `hidden` property expression would be

```
=Parameters!Deliverable.Value <> "ABC" AND Parameters!Deliverable.Value <> "All"
```

So in this example, it reads "Hide if both ABC and All are not selected"

Comment: The Visibility.Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ contains an error: [BC30277] Type character '!' does not match declared data type 'Object'.
----------------------------
The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid.
----------------------------
An error occurred during local report processing. Receiving that error.

Comment: Sorry wrong syntax. It should be <> nstead of !+ I will update the answer

Comment: That still doesn't give me the values of the table when I select them "All".

Comment: It worked, there was a little query error on my end! Thank you!